# Can a Spring Boot convention change?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I understand that Spring Boot goes convention over configuration, providing standard defaults instead of having to explicitly write the configuration (Auto-configuration)

Is it possible that any default value can change in the future?

For example we have an application and let the value for a

`rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency`

to be the default, then is it possible that the default value changes (in a future release), because the convention changes from 20 to 10 (just throwing random numbers to make my point)

Comment: If it changes, does it really impact your system ? If so, set the value yourself, if not don't change. It's unlikely to change and you probably have more important problems to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes. One example I have seen is the change (with Undertow server)/unification of `server.max-http-header-size` in Spring Boot 2.1:

- [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13831)
- [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/14234)
- [Mention in the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#consistent-max-http-header-size-across-all-embedded-web-servers)

I guess changes happen for a [good] reason though. So if you are concerned about sth in particular - follow release notes, test and possibly hardcode important settings.